# How to hide a files from Filezilla (or from directory search)

Tags: file-permissions, putty, filezilla

What are the ways that I can hide files and folders from any directory search ?

For example :
(What I will do)
Access the remote server through putty
Then will show the files inside the folder

(What I WANT to do)
To hide the files inside those folder

(What I tried to do)
I tried to changed the file permission via FileZilla (Doesn't work)
I tried to create a new filter rules via FileZilla (It works but only hides from filezilla)

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

> What are the ways that I can hide files and folders from any directory search ?

There is no such thing as "hiding a file".

In Windows you can set the hidden or system flag, but this doesn't actually hide the file, it's just a filter for directory search operations that *choose* to ignore hidden or system files.

They would be invisible to `dir` but completely visible to `dir /ash`

In *nix, files that start with a "." are not shown by default but that's also just a convention. They're not actually hidden and are just suppressed by file operations that don't want to show "dot" files.

`ls` would not show `.mysecretfile` but `ls -la` would show it.

Comment: Thank you Sir for enlightened me. I now understand. By the way, since it is impossible to completely hide the file from dir, is it possible to hide it by setting a password ?

Comment: The only way to make a file invisible/inaccessible is to set the file permissions so that the current user doesn't have access. In both Windows and *nix, you can give a different user or group permissions to the file and revoke permissions from the user/group you want to hide it from.